# .bat file for copy-pasting folder in Windows XP

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy-paste

I need to copy-paste a folder (files + subfolders) into a BackUpfolder.  I also need to append the time into the BackUp folder name. `xcopy` command is letting me copy only files.  Your help would be appreciated.

Source Folder = `"C:\Documents and Settings.....\Project"` (has many files + subfolders)
Target Folder = `"C:\Backup-Date/time of backup"` Eg Bacup:May 16 2011 12:30 AM

I plan to run this bat file through Scheduler. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCOPY

Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder. XCOPY is similar to the COPY command except that it has additional switches to specify both the source and destination in detail.

XCOPY is particularly useful when copying files from CDROM to a hard drive, as it will automatically remove the read-only attribute.

Syntax
      XCOPY source [destination] [options]

/S           Copy folders and subfolders

/E           Copy folders and subfolders, including Empty folders.
                May be used to modify /T.

/H           Copy hidden and system files and folders (default=N)
Key
   source      : Pathname for the file(s) to be copied.

destination : Pathname for the new file(s).

There are several options you can look at :http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Soruce: http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Comment: Thanks Luis.  I am still not able to merge time into the destination folder name.  Google doesn't help directly.  Still checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think reading the documentation of xcopy would go a long way.